# Tapping on a New badge message in Feed doesn't do anything

Tags: bug, badges, android-app

The feed shows that you've earned a New Badge, but tapping on it doesn't do anything.

[image]

I'd expect it to take you to the page which shows for what question/answer/activity the badge was awarded

Comment: So the app really displays a notification in your feed any time a new unanswered question is posted on Stack Overflow? You must be *swimming* in noise.

Comment: @CodyGray The push notification is only if you have something in your inbox, but yeah, the feed can get kinda busy especially if you're active on on many *cough*ChrisF*cough* sites

Comment: The new feed has been changed since this was created and I'm no longer able to reproduce this.